# Laravel Duplicated queries in foreach

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

hey everyone I'm trying to make my laravel app faster and what I see in debug bar is so many duplicated queries
[image]

and why this happens?  because I'm calculating discount in the product model and when I'm getting products in my foreach I use $product->discount() and let's see what's happening in the Product model and discount function, there it is

```
public function discount(){
        $seller = ProductSeller::orderBy('price','asc')-where('product_id',$this->id)->first();
        $sellerDiscount = Discount::where('seller_id',$seller->seller_id)-latest('created_at')->first();
        $brandDiscount = Discount::where('brand_id',$this->brand_id)-latest('created_at')->first();
        $categoryDiscount = Discount::whereIn('category_id',$cateName)-latest('created_at')->first();
}
```

these are the queries that are duplicating in my category pages in a foreach any idea to prevent the duplicating of each query?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it happens, because you are calling function(`$product->discount()`) instead of getting data from that. Try to use eager load to fix this.

And then get data like this,

```
$product->seller
```

You can do this from Your main query and put condition in that.